# Get the slush stratum proxy working on a mac

Tags: miner-configuration, mac, stratum, proxy

Title says it all - can anyone walk me through setting this up on a mac? I ran the linux python install script but i'm guessing i'm missing a few dependencies as it failed on me.

edit: there are numerous errors, listed here:

```
Reading http://tmrc.mit.edu/mirror/twisted/Twisted/9.0/
Download error on http://tmrc.mit.edu/mirror/twisted/Twisted/9.0/: [Errno 61] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://tmrc.mit.edu/mirror/twisted/Twisted/10.0/
Download error on http://tmrc.mit.edu/mirror/twisted/Twisted/10.0/: [Errno 61] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/
Reading http://tmrc.mit.edu/mirror/twisted/Twisted/8.2/
Download error on http://tmrc.mit.edu/mirror/twisted/Twisted/8.2/: [Errno 61] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://tmrc.mit.edu/mirror/twisted/Twisted/8.1/
Download error on http://tmrc.mit.edu/mirror/twisted/Twisted/8.1/: [Errno 61] Connection refused -- Some packages may not be found!

Running Twisted-12.3.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-OQqo5N/Twisted-12.3.0/egg-dist-tmp-9vucfj
unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Knowing the error message would quite obviously be important to be able to help you...

Comment: good point. added to question.

Comment: `unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory` seems to indicate that you do not have a compiler installed. Did you set up Xcode and install the command line tools, or install GCC through MacPorts or Homebrew?

Comment: Aah, I've been a fool, the command line tools have apparently been optional addons for Xcode since 4.2 so I assumed i had gcc but did not. Got them from xcode preferences/downloads. Thank you! Works fine now. Worryingly though, gcc will no longer be an option for future versions of Xcode (4.6 forwards)

Comment: Any reason this has to be so difficult? Ah, to show that the devs are so much smarter than the rest of us!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, while Mac includes python it does not include gcc by default, even once you've installed Xcode 4.2 or later. For now, grab that, go to preferences, downloads and get the command line tools.

Once a version of Xcode higher than 4.6 is out you'll have to find a new way to install gcc on your mac, as gcc will no longer be included, but I guess that's a question for another stackexchange, and likely a macports or homebrew solution.